# Custom DELETE/TRIM brush in Sculpt Mode

Tags: modeling, sculpting, geometry, sculpt, sculpt-mode

Could someone figure out how to create a custom delete brush in Sculpt Mode?

So when you click on geometry it erases the faces.

For example, delete the faces inside the red rectangle. So then you can smooth it with the "Smooth" brush:
[image]

Thank you very much

Miguel

Comment: I have no idea what a custom delete brush is. Why not add a brief description about it to your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Now it's updated

Comment: Thanks for the update of the question. So you want a brush that can paint holes into the mesh? "Holes" means deleted faces and the mesh will no longer be manifold (watertight). I'm just wonder because usually you want to avoid holes in a high-poly sculpted mesh. They only cause problems.

Comment: Thank you, Blunder. Not holes but protuberances/bumps. Sorry if it's not the correct word. I updated it again.

Comment: Have you already tried the *Trim* brush? I think this is what you are looking for. It works internally like a boolean operation. You can click and hold the *Box Trim* brush to choose it or the *Lasso Trim* brush. For complex meshes the operation can take a while. The created colored areas are *Face Sets* (just if you wonder).

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much! How could I select your answer as the correct answer?

Comment: One last question, any way to speed up the workflow when working with complex meshes? It's a yaw mesh:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lBB2Xkq7Q7b4SC5LvhQzUtI34n--rp_a/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The (Slow) Delete Brush**

In the *Sculpt* mode you can delete geometry with the *Box Trim* or *Lasso Trim* brush. Click and hold the brush icon in the toolbar to select one of them.

The *Trim* brush performs a Boolean operation. Unfortunately this can be very slow for high-poly meshes. A similiar brush is the *Line Project* that removes the geometry on one side of the brush.

[image: trim brushes]

**A Faster Alternative**

For your mesh (250k vertices, 500k faces) these brushes are very slow. A faster approach would be the *Edit* mode. **(1)** Activate the X-ray mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and then **(2)** use the *Select Lasso* to select part of the mesh and delete the selected vertices (<kbd>X</kbd>). This is much faster.

[image: edit mode]

Other helpful selection tools are *Selected Linked* (hover mouse or select one vert and press <kbd>L</kbd>) and *invert* the selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to remove other loose mesh parts. The *Select Circle*  tool (<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the selection) might be also an option to select a part of the mesh.

[image: selection tools]